# How to turn subpixel antialiasing on in macOS 10.14?

Tags: settings, text, mojave

In macOS 10.14 Mojave Apple turned the «LCD font smoothing» setting (which turned a subpixel antialiasing on) to «*just* font smoothing» setting. So now all the text is rendered just antialiased that looks worse on not-retina displays. How to enable the subpixel antialiasing back?

Comment: Note: The *font smoothing* option is still available under the General panel in System Preferences.  I think you mean to note that  the implementation of font smoothing has changed.

Comment: @ephsmith You are right. But there is no **LCD** font smoothing option anymore.

Comment: Font smoothing _is available on 10.14_. It is located on the bottom of the `System Preferences -> General` panel.

Comment: @ephsmith «Font smoothing» and «LCD font smoothing» are different features

Comment: Good point! I agree. That's a good clarification to make *explicitly* so that viewers aren't misled to think no smoothing is available.  This is why I mentioned the implementation has changed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Open the Terminal application
2. Type or paste

   ```
   defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool NO
   ```
3. Press <kbd>↩︎</kbd> (Enter)
4. Restart the computer

---

To return it back, do the same but instead type in the terminal

```bsh
defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool YES
```

---

Update on 2019.10.12: the solution works in macOS 10.15 too.

---

Update on 2019.12.24: you can turn subpixel antialiasing only in a specific application. To achieve it, do the same but instead type in the terminal

```bsh
defaults write com.evernote.Evernote CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool NO
```

where `com.evernote.Evernote` is the identifier of the application. See how to get it in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/346369/776859). Then restart the application.

To revert it, type in the terminal

```bsh
defaults delete com.evernote.Evernote CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled
```

You can even enable subpixel antialiasing everywhere and disable in a specific application (it's left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: No need to restart? Just Logout/login? – I read that feature was gone for good.  Not using Mojave: can you post pictures of the difference for proof?

Comment: Any app you launch after that will be properly anti aliased. Restart is needed if you want to refresh the whole user interface.

Comment: Testing this on my Apple TB Display on Mojave: FontSmoothingDisabled FALSE looks more pixelated and less smooth than with TRUE, which is counter to what you'd expect.

Comment: @benwiggy I expect a subpixel antialiasing. It may look good or bad depending on the monitor.

Comment: @Finesse I took screenshots and then zoomed in on them to show the before and after. I'd be interested to see yours, and what monitor you're using.

Comment: This does not work, at least on my setup with macOS 10.15.2. Maybe I have another issue here. It would help if this answer would show screen shots of text rendered with this setting turned on and off to see whether it is talking about the same thing as was asked in the question.

Comment: I remain unconvinced that sub-pixel rendering exists on MacOS in Mojave and later.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the accepted answer, you may need to turn off the new "*just* font smoothing" implementation after enabling subpixel antialiasing. This solves the pixelated text issue user [benwiggy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/198019/benwiggy) commented about on a 13.3" mid-2012 MacBook Pro (1280 x 800 non-retina screen) and especially for very small font sizes. By leaving the font smoothing option enabled simultaneously with subpixel antialiasing, the text weight appears inconsistent and "pixelated".

I doubt screenshots will do the visible difference justice, but here are some comparisons anyway. (All screenshots were taken after `defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool NO` and logging out to enable subpixel antialiasing systemwide.)

[image: Comparison in System Preferences - General Pane]
[image: Comparison in Safari - Tabs]

Comment: Your screen shots show no evidence of subpixel rendering/anti-aliasing. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering for example screen shots.

Comment: You’re right. Unfortunately, subpixel rendering doesn’t work properly in Catalina. In 10.15, the command just makes fonts appear thinner. Of course, it is suggested to use the new font smoothing implementation if smooth text similar to previous versions is what you’re after. Some others wrote about it at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250998388 and at https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/dmntf5/comment/f9mdqia

Comment: @AlexLiu Using Tinkertool https://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html, I enabled FontSmoothing on Catalina and set `Strong` smoothing which I prefer. Thought I've not quite understood what is the technical difference between the three levels.

Comment: That "Use font smoothing when available" is not there for me on macOS 11.1.